# How can I find manuals for old Kelty equipment?

Tags: gear, children

I've come across a Kelty Kids carrier.  The tag says 'Kangaroo', and the date code on it is F11-95, style 21959030.  I've called Kelty and looked on their website.  The problem is that the Kangaroo is a soft front carry pouch style, and this is more like their traditional hard frame carrier with a kickstand.  They are not able to tell me what this product is, and seem quite confused by the information I've given them.  I'd really like a manual for it so I can use it safely.  Are there any other sources of information that I can turn to?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you post a picture?

Comment: @RussellSteen pictures added

Comment: Yeah, not sure what you have there.  I've been looking and can't find anything even sort of close.  I'll ask the guy at the used gear store next time I'm over there.

Comment: Was there any update to this question? I just picked up the same model, and I would really like a manual or something of that sort.

Comment: Alternatively - what is it you are wanting the manual for? It may be that you can ask that here and get an answer.

Comment: @RoryAlsop I guess I just feel more comfortable with manuals for certain pieces of equipment - there are lots of straps and buckles on this, so I just want to make sure I'm using it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

This may be what you're searching for: [kelty-baby-carriers-kelty-kangar](http://www.docstoc.com/docs/33662625/kelty-baby-carriers-kelty-kangar)

You can only watch it for free online, I haven't found it yet in any other free website.

Comment: Looks pretty close to me

Comment: No, that's a soft sided front carrier, not a framed backpack carrier